# Chai with should: How to not break code that uses properties named "should"?

Tags: javascript, chai

I am using Chai with should. Works great. However when I try to work with an object that has a property named `should` I run into trouble:

```
// object under test
function run() {
    var x = {};
    console.log('typeof should:', typeof(x.should)); // 'object'

    if (x.should == null) {
        console.log('initializing x.should');
        x.should = [];
    }

    // TypeError: Object #<Assertion> has no method 'push';
    x.should.push('foobar')
}

// test code
var chai = require('chai');
chai.should();
run();
```

When I run this code with Mocha, the condition is never true and hence the property `should` is never initialized.

Since the problem arises in an included library (elastic.js to be precise) modifying the object under test is not an option.

Is there any way I can still use Chai's should?

Comment: Try `if (!x.hasOwnProperty("should") || x.should==null)`

Comment: Nice try. :-) Sadly, the "production" code is part of a library I have no control over. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: In that case, prevent `chai` from extending `Object.prototype` (it really shouldn't do that), or run it in a different window (iframe, whatever)

Comment: How could I prevent this? It happens here: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/interface/should.js#L35

Comment: I dunno, file a bug against the test suite and let it's author figure out. Until it's fixed, you can `delete Object.prototype.should`.

Comment: Deleting the prototype method would equal omittin `chai.should()` in the first place. However I like the library... Guess I'll file the bug. Thanks!

Comment: --> https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/283

Comment: Now having read `chai`s documentation, why don't you just use `expect` instead of `should`?

Comment: Got the same reply on GitHub. Well, `expect`, here I come. :-/